# Antlr and link failed

Tags: c++, antlr

I am working with ANTLR, and Visual Studio 2011 beta, and I got the following errors in the compilation ... :/
I've recompiled the antlr.lib, I tried everything ... which may be?
I tested also with antlr 2.7.5...

```
antlr.lib(TokenRefCount.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(TokenRefCount.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/SAFESEH' specification
antlr.lib(BitSet.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(RecognitionException.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(MismatchedCharException.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(CharBuffer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(CharScanner.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(NoViableAltForCharException.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(Token.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(ASTRefCount.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(BaseAST.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(TokenBuffer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(MismatchedTokenException.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(ASTFactory.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(Parser.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(LLkParser.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(NoViableAltException.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(CommonAST.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(String.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(InputBuffer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
antlr.lib(CommonToken.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in tard_lexer.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in tard_lexer.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in tard_lexer.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in tard_lexer.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xbad_alloc(void)" (?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xthrow.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::locale::id::id(unsigned int)" (??0id@locale@std@@QAE@I@Z) already defined in tard_lexer.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "char const * __cdecl std::_Syserror_map(int)" (?_Syserror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(syserror.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(syserror.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: struct std::_Iterator_base12 * * __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Getpfirst(void)const " (?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ) already defined in tard_lexer.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl std::uncaught_exception(void)" (?uncaught_exception@std@@YA_NXZ) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(uncaught.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(__int64)" (?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & (__cdecl*)(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &))" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in tard_parser.obj
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::endl(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?endl@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@AAV21@@Z) already defined in tard_parser.obj
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(tolower.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isprint already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
../../dist/debug\test_vc_7_1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your project Runtime library?
I think you include some default libraries which are not supposed to use in your Runtime option. Just set your libraries and Runtime option as mentioned in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and ignore the rest based on the table.